# Select rails 3 assets based on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a Rails 3 application, I would like to be able to use unminified javascript and css files in my development environment for debugging and such, and minified versions in production.

I can think of a few hacky solutions, but ideally I'd like `javascript_include_tag` and friends to automatically select the right asset file.

Ideas?

Comment: @JiříPospíšil wow thanks, never occurred to me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your js normally using

```
javascript_include_tag
```

In your `development.rb` set:

```
config.assets.compress = false
```

and in production.rb use:

```
config.assets.compress = true
```